# Using NC in a .htaccess file not working

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am trying to create an .htaccess file that ignores the case sensitivity of my files. I have the following so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

This works when I type the file name exactly. For example, one of my files is About.html. When I type in www.domain.com/About, it goes to the right place, but when I type in www.domain.com/about, it does not.

I have seen posts about people using [NC], but I cannot get that to work either. I have also tried putting

```
CaseInsensitive On
```

But that seems to break everything (couldn't even load the home page), so I took that bit out. Does anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Case-insensitivity won't magically turn "about" into "About".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case insensitivity does not work like that, it activates case insensitivity for the regular expression matching, not the files.

For example :

```
RewriteRule ^somefile.php$ /index.php
RewriteRule ^somefile.php$ /index2.php [NC]
```

if someone try to access `http://domain.com/SomeFile.php`, it will not match the first line but the second line will, this will redirect him to index2.php (and not index.php). But if you the index2.php file is named instead INDEX2.php, the redirection will throw a 404 not found error.

What you are looking for is using RewriteMap. you need to put this in you server configuration file :

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

Restart apache, and use a rule in your htacces like this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /${lc:$1}
```

This will turn any request to lower case, your files then must be all lowercased.

More informations about RewriteMap => [see documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap)

Comment: When doing what you suggested, I get an Internal Service Error on every page. Even when navigating to the exact file.

Comment: where did you add the rewritemap ?

Comment: After the code I have up there. Should I be putting it before it? 

`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d `
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f` 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html`
`RewriteMap lc int:tolower`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /${lc:$1}`

Comment: As I said, RewriteMap does not go in the htacces, it goes in the apache condifuration file (that's why your are getting an internal server error), read the documenation for further informations on where to put the rewritemap